# Convert array.count to String

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to convert an array.count to String values for the count, i.e.
array.count = 5 should return ["0","1","2","3","4"]

I've tried

```
var strRow = array.map { String($0) }
return strRow
```

but it's not working the way it should. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You still want the return to be an array? but of string?

Comment: That is correct yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`return Array(0...array.count)`

if you want array of Strings, then just map it
`Array(0...array.count).map{String($0)}`

Comment: I get an error "Value of type 'Int' has no member 'map'.

Comment: you are not copying correctly, probably you are mapping the count and not the array.

Comment: @CorBrink ogres answer is only one line of code compared to my answer. As he mentioned probably you are mapping the count.
Try this 
var strArray = Array(0...array.count).map{String($0)}
print(strArray)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Hint are in the Code Comments):

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // array.count = 5
var stringArray = [String]()

// 0 ... array.count to go from 0 to 5 included
for index in 0 ... array.count {
    // append index with cast it to string
    stringArray.append(String(index))
}

print(stringArray)
// result -> ["0","1","2","3","4","5"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question you give an example that array of count 5 should be transformed to `["0","1","2","3","4","5"]`, that's a 6-count array, are you sure this is what you need? I will assume that you want 5-count array to be transformed to `["0","1","2","3","4"]`, please correct me in the comments if I'm wrong.

Here's the solution I propose:

```
let array = [5,5,5,5,5] // count 5

let stringIndices = array.indices.map(String.init)
// ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
```